# ¿Es posible conceder permisos de lectura sobre information_schema.innodb_%?

Tags: mysql, permisos

(MySQL 5.7 - En la verdión 8 ya no existe este inconveniente)

Estoy tratando de concederle permisos de lectura a un usuario sobre las tablas `innodb_sys_foreign` y `innodb_sys_foreign_cols` de `information_schema` para que pueda obtener información sobre a qué campos hacen referencias las claves foraneas.

El usuario puede leer sin problemas todas las tablas que no comienzan con "innodb_", pero con éstas recibe el siguiente error:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_sys_fields;

ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation
```

Intenté ingresar como "root" y solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
GRANT SELECT ON information_schema.innodb_sys_foreign TO 'user'@'host';

ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'host' to database 'information_schema'
```

¿Es normal que el usuario "root" tenga esas restricciones? ¿Hay alguna manera apropiada de solucionarlo, por ejemplo, creando una vista y concediendo allí los permisos; editando directamente la tabla donde se almacenan los privilegios; obteniendo la información sobre claves foraneas de otro sitio?

Comment: `information_schema` no es una tabla en sí misma, por tanto, tus esfuerzos no deben orientarse a otorgar permisos con respecto a `information_schema`, lo que dice el MR al respecto es bastante claro: [*For most INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables, **each MySQL user has the right to access them**, but can see only the rows in the tables that correspond to objects for which the user has the proper access privileges.*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-introduction.html#information-schema-privileges) ...

Comment: En otras palabras, los permisos para acceder a información mediante `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` dependen de los permisos que el usuario tenga en los objetos en sí mismos, por tanto, debes ocuparte de otorgar permisos adecuados en aquellas tablas de las que quieres extrar información en este contexto. Claro está que debes conocer las consecuencias a las que te expones otorgando dichos permisos. ¿Debe realmente ese usuario tener permisos sobre esas tablas? Si no debe, quizá necesites replantear la lógica de lo que intentas hacer, o bien ofrecer la informacón mediante vistas.

Comment: Lo de crear una vista me parecía la opción más prolija. Voy a probar con eso a ver si funciona y actualizo. Gracias.

Comment: Me sigue pidiendo el privilegio `PROCESS` para acceder a la vista que creé dentro de la base de datos en la que el usuario tiene todos los privilegios. ¿Será más seguro concederle los permisos en esa vista?

Comment: Lo pude solucionar creando un procedimiento almacenado con el usuario "root". Después voy a ver cómo restringir el comportamiento para que sea un poco más seguro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decidí usar un procedimiento almacenado definido por un usuario que tiene acceso a `information_schema.innodb_*`, aprovechando que se ejecutan con los permisos de dicho usuario.

```
  DELIMITER //
  CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name_ejemplo
  (IN db CHAR(123))
  BEGIN
  # Restringir valores de 'db'
  SELECT id, for_name FROM information_schema.innodb_sys_foreign
  WHERE id like CONCAT(db, "/%");
  END //
  DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Dejo abierta la pregunta por si surge alguna solución mejor.

Comment: Lo malo de esta solución es que hay que crear el sp en cada base de datos desde donde queramos usarlo. También probé creando un after insert trigger en mysql.user para que agregue permisos de seleccion en una base de datos en la que estaba el sp, pero no está permitido. Finalmente actualicé de mysql 5.7 a 8.0 y las vistas `information_schema.innodb_*` son accesibles incluso para usuarios recién creados sin ningún privilegio.

Comment: También tuve que actualizar de php7.2 al 8 para poder conectarme a MySQL sin tener que cambiar a la versión antigua del hash de contraseñas.